# Java: работа с текстом

Tags: java, текст, редактор-текста

Делаю простейший редактор текста на Java - никак не могу решить проблему. Эта программа работает. Но как сделать так, чтобы написал какой-то текст, нажал Enter, он сохранил, потом снова запустил программу, но чтоб новый написанный текст был уже с новой строки, а не слитно, типа чтоб создавался некий такой список?

- Машина
- Дерево
- Бумага и т. д.

а не так МашинаДеревоБумага.

Мой код - режим считывателя текста:

```
System.out.println("Режим редактора включен:\n Вводите текст!");
try (FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(soxr + "/" + ffile + ".txt", true)) {
    // запись всей строки
    Scanner nawtekst = new Scanner(System.in);
    String text = nawtekst.nextLine();
    writer.write(text);
    writer.write("\n");
    // запись по символам
    writer.append("\n");
    writer.append("");
    writer.flush();
} catch (IOException ex) {
    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
} finally {
    System.out.println();
    String put = soxr + "/" + ffile + ".txt";
    System.out.println("Файл сохранен путь к файлу: " + put);
}
```

При считывании он читает именно так, как я хочу, то есть с новой строки, но не знаю, почему в самом блокноте сами слова не с новой строки.

```
System.out.println("Вы перешли в режим чтения файла!\n\n");
System.out.println("Пожалуйста введите путь к вашему файлу!\n");
Scanner rd = new Scanner(System.in);
String FilePath = rd.nextLine();
try (FileReader reader = new FileReader(FilePath)) {
    // читаем посимвольно
    int c;
    while ((c = reader.read()) != -1) {
        System.out.print((char) c);
    }
} catch (IOException ex) {
    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: у вас в файл текст записывается в одну строку или  в файле все с разной но при чтении у вас это получается одной строкой не смотря на это? Код считывателя можете добавить

Comment: А как сделать так чтобы после каждого ввода слова или предложения, он записывался с новой строки?

Comment: Я вам вопрос задал)

Comment: Добавил, но наврятли он как-то вам поможет :D

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: Да, я уже выбрал ответ))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если проблема лишь с переносом строк, то можно использовать пару-тройку вариантов.

**Первый**

Использовать разделитель строк самой системы. А конкретно `line.separator`. Его можно увидеть [тут в списке](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperties()).

Чтобы его "вызвать" - надо написать `System.getProperty("line.separator")`, т.е. Система, дай мне твое свойство с таким-то именем, а именно "разделитель строк"

И дальше его использовать:

```
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("myfile.txt", true);
Scanner nawtekst = new Scanner(System.in);
String text = nawtekst.nextLine();
writer.write(text);
writer.write(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
writer.flush();
```

либо сокращенно (вынести разделитель куда-либо и многократно его использовать):

```
final String separator = System.getProperty("line.separator");
writer.write(text + separator);
writer.write("another text" + separator);
```

**Второй**

Использовать обертки для `FileWriter`, например `BufferedWriter`

```
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("file.txt", true);
BufferedWriter bufferWriter = new BufferedWriter(writer);
for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    bufferWriter.write("bufferWriter_" + i);
    bufferWriter.newLine();
}

bufferWriter.close();
```

`newLine()` - будет добавлять новую строку

**Третий**

Использовать другие потоки:

```
PrintStream fileStream = new PrintStream(new File("file.txt"));
fileStream.println("your data");
```

`println` - будет добавлять с новой строки сразу

---

`PrintStream` вкупе с `FileOutputStream`:

```
PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("file.txt", true), true);
for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    printStream.println("printStream_" + i);
}

printStream.close();
```

---

Кстати в Java 7 теперь есть [`System.lineSeparator()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#lineSeparator--) метод.

Comment: Ура!) Сработало) Спасибо вам!)))

Comment: Также можно в конец строки дописывать \r\n для переноса в Windows.