# Как записывать в файл строки с переносом строки?

Tags: java, файлы, filestream

Есть такой код.

```
File f = new File("aa.txt");
File f1 = new File("bb.txt");
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(f1);
int a;
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
String str;
ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();
while((str=br.readLine())!=null){
    arr.add(str);
}
str="";
for(String s : arr){
str+=s+"\n";
}
System.out.println(str);
byte[] b = str.getBytes();
out.write(b);
out.close();
```

Содержимое файла "аа" - несколько строк. Соответственно хотелось бы перенести текст (предварительно отформатировав его) в файл "bb".
Основной вопрос - как записать в файл информацию с переносом строк. Пробовал создавать строку с управляющими символами, но судя по всему их не читает поток.

Comment: поможет что-то отсюда? http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/533079/191482

Comment: OS какая? Под линуксом, например, ваш код работает без проблем, `"\n"` пишутся и не пищат.

Comment: @PinkTux Вместо `\n` лучше использовать `Environment.NewLine`

Comment: @Bulson, *"Под линуксом, например"*.

Comment: @PinkTux Win7 моя ОС

Comment: @Bulson можно пример использования?

Comment: Кажется возникла проблема кодировки. У меня вместо перевода на новую строку по методам 2 и 3 указанным по ссылке выше, пишет в файл неопознанный символ какой-то. UPD По всем трем методам выводит символ ਍, 127ой вроде как в ASCII

Comment: @Сергей извиняй брат, я не из вашего мира джавы, а из мира дотнета сюда случайно попал... Лучше все же указывать в тегах на тему какого языка идет вопрос, а не только "файлы" и "filestream"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

лучше использовать `StringBuilder`. 
`System.lineSeparator()` или же `System.getProperty("line.separator")` в зависимости от ОС определяет нужный тебе символ .

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for(String s : arr){
        sb.append(s).append(System.lineSeparator());
    }
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
    byte[] b = sb.toString().getBytes();
    out.write(b);
    out.close();
```

**UPD**

Посмотрите что за символ у вас не отображается 
Следующий код позволит узнать код символа и как выглядит

```
    byte[] bytes = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(file);
    for(int i =0; i< bytes.length ; i++){
        System.out.println("As the bytem value: "+ bytes[i]);//as the numeric byte value
        System.out.println("Converted as char to printiong to the screen: "+ String.valueOf((char)bytes[i]));
    }
```

Comment: Не сработало, тот же символ

Comment: @Сергей обновил ответ. попробуйте  и скажите что за символ не ведите

Comment: As the bytem value: 13
Converted as char to printiong to the screen: 
As the bytem value: 10
Converted as char to printiong to the screen: 

это управляющие последовательности для перевода строки(10) и возврата каретки(13). Я гуглил.
Просто не отрабатывает
там еще мини вопрос, при чтении в строк первые два символа записывает как "эя", но перезаписывает потом нормально.

Comment: @Сергей то есть проблемы нет, но есть вопрос почему  "эя" ? 
>> первые два символа записывает как "эя"
куда записывает? как смотрите ?

Comment: Проблема осталась. Но ко всему прочему не понимаю механизм образования первых двух байтов) там в строку записывает в самом начале (юя), но записывает в файл потом без этих байтов. Возможно это интерпретируется как специфический управляющий символ, не знаю)
Ошибся, записывает в начало (юя)

Comment: куда записывает? как смотрите ? в какую строку записывает?

Comment: Знаком "\n" буду показывать перенос строки, естественно). Так вот, в первоначальном файле записано что-то наподобие aa"\n"bbb"\n"cc. Мне необходимо перенести информацию(отформатировав ее предварительно) в другой файл. Соответственно просто побайтово записывать\копировать через FileUtils.Copy(file1,file2)(кажется так) не вариант. Считываю так: 
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
    String str;
    ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();
    while((str=br.readLine())!=null){
    arr.add(str);
    }

Comment: При выводе строки str на консоль получается в самом начале "юя a a "
Затем формитрую(сортирую) и перезаписываю строку с управляющими символами BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(f1,true));
     for(String s : arr){
      bw.write(s);
      bw.write("\r");
      bw.write("\n");
     }
Записывает как и надо, но без переносов строки(нет символов юя)

Comment: @Сергей вы же говорите, что у вас первые 2 символа в файле 10 и 13 соответственно. пробуйте создать новый файл. дописать туда ваши строки(не копировать(!) а руками дописать!) и повторить все с этим файлом уже

Comment: Это не первые два символа. Первые два символа "ю" и "я" соответственно. Просто тот неопознанный символ возвращает байты(используя ваш код) с кодами 13 и 10(возврат каретки и перенос строки соответственно). Пробовал уже всеми способами, код судя по всему верный(один и тот же результат всеми способами), скорее всего проблема на моей стороне, но не могу понять в чем

Comment: @Сергей давайте так: прикладываете файл и код, присылаете ссылку и мы смотрим уже

Comment: https://ru.files.fm/u/4443mm6s В архиве изображения код2 и код3 дают такой результат как и код1.

Comment: @Сергей твой код у меня работает корректно. пока не знаю чем тебе помочь

Comment: Это может быть специфика отображения в блокноте? Мб через что другое открыть. я уже теряюсь в догадках.

Comment: UPD. Открыл через MS Word i Word Pad, перенос строки присутствует, но остаются символы в начале (яю). Пока пропущу этот вопрос, а то ничего нового не изучу, если начну разбираться)

Comment: Нашел решение. Все очевидное просто. Сменил кодировку в Eclipse. Была cp1251, сменил на UTF-8